# Не могу найти пример Call back'а из асинхронной функции

Tags: c++, c++11, callback, асинхронность

Меня интересует возврат значения из асинхронной функции не используя метод фьючерса .get(),что бы была возможность не дожидаться завершения асинхронной функции.

Comment: Пожалуйста уточните что именно вы пытаетесь сделать, что уже пробовали, и что пошло не так. Приведите ваш код если он есть. Из заголовка и вопроса не понятно что вы пытаетесь сделать, callback на метод класса? Или callback на глобальную функцию.

Answer (score 1):

Да написать-то несложно, но вы бы поточнее сказали, что именно вас интересует? **Формально** [вот это](https://ideone.com/FI9Uiv) - вызов callback'а (не только по названию :))

```
void callback1(const char * s)
{
    cout << "-->" << s << endl;
}

void callback2(const char * s)
{
    cout << "==>" << s << endl;
}

void async_func(const char * s, void(*back)(const char*))
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        back(s);
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(10));
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    future<void> f = async(async_func,"First",callback1);
    future<void> g = async(async_func,"Second",callback2);
    f.get();
    g.get();
}
```

**Update**

С учетом внесенных уточнений - держите:

```
void callback1(const char * s)
{
    cout << "-->" << s << endl;
}

void callback2(const char * s)
{
    cout << "==>" << s << endl;
}

void async_func(const char * s, void(*back)(const char*))
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        back(s);
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(10));
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    thread(async_func,"First",callback1).detach();
    thread(async_func,"Second",callback2).detach();
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(10));
}
```

Только учтите, что в этом случае вы не сможете, например, нормально обработать исключения и т.д. и т.п. - словом, работа с `thread` куда сильнее ограничена, чем с `async`...

Comment: После уточнения вопроса (если таковое последует), ваш ответ рискует превратиться в "неявляется ответом" :-)

Comment: @Uranus или быть уточненным с учетом вновь открывшихся обстоятельств :) А вообще - золотое правило: при неясном ТЗ результат - ХЗ.

Comment: Меня интересует возврат значения из асинхронной функции не используя метод фьючерса .get(),что бы была возможность не дожидаться завершения асинхронной функции.

Comment: Ну так и надо было писать :) См. дополненный ответ.